# Global form attribute in Symfony 2 form

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2.4.  What I am trying to do is to set form attributes on the form level which are accessible to each individual widget.

I have a custom form theme which can render the form slightly differently if it is a horizontal or vertical layout. I'd like to be able to specify `{ 'horizontal': true }` as an attribute on the form, then be able to read it while I'm reading each widget.

Is it possible?  I want to avoid needing to do this on every widget.

```
{{ form_row(form.person.province, {horizontal:true}) }}
{{ form_row(form.person.postalCode, {horizontal:true}) }}
{{ form_row(form.person.phone, {horizontal:true}) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couldn't you achieve that in your own form theme?

```
{% block form_row %}
  {% spaceless %}
  {% if horizontal|default(true) %} {# or something along these lines #}
    ...
  {% else %}
    ...
  {% endif %}
  {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

Comment: I have my own form theme and have done something like that.  My question is how to set horizontal=true when I'm rendering the form, rather than having to set it on each form_row() call

Comment: @Teddy it's already in the answer i provided "{% if horizontal|default(true) %}"  use the default filter in your form theme to set the value of horizontal if it has not been provided. and having it be provided will just override the default value.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something.  I have that in my form theme already (see my whole fields.html.twig here: http://fpaste.org/104706/).  My default is false.  Your way I'd still need to override horizontal to false on each row for vertical forms.  I simply want to avoid having to say {horizontal:true} on each form_row, rather set it on the form level itself and be able to access it from the fields.

Comment: add a default to you form_row block then

{% block form_row %}
{% if horizontal|default(true) %}
<div class="form-group">
{{ form_label(form, {horizontal:horizontal}) }}
{{ form_errors(form, {horizontal:horizontal}) }}
{{ form_widget(form, {horizontal:horizontal}) }}
</div>
{% endblock form_row %}